# Slidify: How to call image as background from assets/img folder?

Tags: r, yaml, slidify

I want to call an image from the assets/img folder, becuase I want to share the deck in a ZIP and therefore they won't have the same path as I do for my files.

I've modify the "slidify.css" file, as usual, but with a path to the assets/img folder.

This is the path where the CSS is:

`D:\presentaciones\prueba\libraries\frameworks\io2012\css`

Path to the image:

`D:\presentaciones\prueba\assets\img`

Path to index:

`D:\presentaciones\prueba`

These were my attemps:

1.-

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: white;
  background-image:url("assets/img/star-bg.png");
}
```

2.-

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: white;
  background-image:url(assets\\img\\star-bg.png);
}
```

3.-

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: white;
  background-image:url("assets\\img\\star-bg.png");
}
```

4.-

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: white;
  background-image:url(".\\assets\\img\\star-bg.png");
}
```

5.-

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: white;
  background-image:url("..\\assets\\img\\star-bg.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the css file is in folder path `/libraries/frameworks/io2012/css/`, it needs to go up 4 levels before it can see `/assets/img/`, so it should be

```
/* relative path */
background-image: url('../../../../assets/img/star-bg.png');
```

or you should be able to use

```
/* absolute path */
background-image: url('/presentaciones/prueba/assets/img/star-bg.png');
```